# MC34063A power consumption calculation

Tags: power, current, current-measurement, power-consumption, mc34063

I'm designing a circuit based on the MC34063A switching regulator to step up 3.7V to 8V.

The 3.7V for Vin comes from a 3.7V Li Ion battery and so I'm trying to calculate the battery life. I'm a bit confused on some of the parameters from the datasheet though. It states that Icc (supply current) is typically 2.5mA. This seems a bit too low to use as a value for the total current consumption. However, I've calculated that Ipk for my application (8V @ 200mA) will be around 1A. I know it's a switching regulator though and so the the waveform for the Ipk value looks more like a triangular waveform. Would an average of Ipk give a better indication of power consumption?

I'm just wondering if anyone would point me in the right direction with regards to calculating total power consumption so that I can calculate my battery life.

Comment: The supply current is the current the regulator needs to run its internal circuitry.

Comment: @Hearth So would I be able to use 2.5mA as the current consumption when calculating the battery life?

Comment: Only if there's no load on the circuit. The 2.5 mA is *only* the current drawn by the regulator itself, there will be additional current drawn by the load, and in a properly designed system the load current will be much greater than the supply current--if it's not, you either chose the wrong controller or you have *very* strict requirements on other things.

Comment: @Hearth Perfect! Thanks. Just to clarify, would I simply add my load current to the 2.5mA to get the total current consumption? My load is 8V @ 200mA.

Comment: No. Remember, a step-up converter will always have higher average input current than output current (and likewise, a step-down converter will have lower average input current than output current).

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to think if it in terms of power. The input power will be the output power divided by the efficiency (say70%) plus the power of the controlling circuitry.

So for 8V @ 200mA the output power is 1600mW. At an efficiency of 70% (not very good but you may not get much better for this circuitry) this is 2280mW. Add the power for the controller (3.7*2.5 = ~10) to get 2290mW.

Divide by the input voltage to get the input current 2290/3.7 = ~620mA. This is subject to a fair amount of variation depending upon the exact circuit used.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the clear explanation. I was struggling to understand it in terms of power consumption.